# Last command and execution time

Tags: command-line, notification

I'd like to get the last command used and its execution time. This will be used as part of an alias for notification.

Comment: By execution time, do you mean time of execution or running time?

Comment: Good point. Both.

Answer (score 4):

#### NOTE: I'm assuming `bash` as the shell.

Adapting to other shells shouldn't be difficult.

Getting the last command used is trivial: it's stored in the shell [event designator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators-1) `!!`, and can also be obtained using the shell builtins `fc` ([`fc -s`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33794/how-can-i-alias-to-last-command)) or `history` (with some string manuipluation: `history 1 | awk '{$1=""}1'`).

Getting the time of execution, or the running time, however, is not, unless some action is taken *before* the command has executed. Once the command is run, nothing can be done - the horses have bolted.

For getting the time of execution, either:

1. Set the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable, which would make `bash` save the time of execution in the history, then use text processing to extract the time from the output of `history`.
2. Use a wrapper to save the execution time manually.

For getting the running time, again, either:

1. If you had set `HISTTIMEFORMAT` before running the command, you could parse the output of `history` to get the execution time and then calculate the run time.
2. Use a wrapper to run the command with `time`: `time some-command`. Processing the output of `time` is a bit messy if you want to leave [the output of the command untouched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457953/how-to-store-a-substring-of-the-output-of-time-function-in-bash-script).
3. Use a wrapper to calculate runtime based on manually saved execution time.

---

### With `HISTTIMEFORMAT` set

If you set the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` variable, then you need not use a wrapper. 
First, in your `.bashrc`, set `HISTTIMEFORMAT`. You can set it to anything, as long as it's not empty. If you don't want your `history` command to show the time, you could set it to a space (`HISTTIMEFORMAT=" "`).

Now, there's an alias present in the default `.bashrc` of Ubuntu:

```bsh
# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
```

We can adapt it for our purposes:

```bsh
alert_post () 
{ 
    RET=$?;
    END=$(date '+%s');
    LAST_COMM="$(HISTTIMEFORMAT='%s '; history 1)";
    START=$(awk '{print $2}' <<<"$LAST_COMM");
    START_TIME=$(date -d"@$START" '+%T %D');
    COMM=$(awk '{print $3}' <<<"$LAST_COMM");
    notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $RET = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$COMM started at $START_TIME finished in $((END - START)) seconds.";
    return $RET
}
alias a=alert_post
```

You can use it thus:

```
$ sleep 10; a
```

---

### Wrapper function

Using a function or a script to wrap around the command:

```bsh
alert_wrapper () 
{ 
    START=$SECONDS;
    START_TIME=$(date '+%T %D');
    COMM="$1";
    "$@";
    RET=$?;
    END=$SECONDS;
    notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $RET = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$COMM started at $START_TIME finished in $((END - START)) seconds."
    return $RET
}
alias a=alertwrapper
```

Then run your command prefixed with `a`:

```
$ a sleep 10
```

---

Notes:

1. There are many ways of getting the time, both execution and runtime. I used both the `$SECONDS` special variable and the `date` command. You could get by with only the `date` command.
2. I have used `notify-usd`, which should be available on standard Ubuntu. You could look at other ways of producing notifications.
3. I have saved the exit status of the command in `$RET` and [returned it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419952/difference-between-return-and-exit-in-bash-functions), so you should be able to rely on exit codes: `do-something; a || echo "Couldn't do something."` or `a do-something || echo "Couldn't do something."` will `echo` if `do-something` had a non-zero exit status.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and I'm sorry it wasn't accepted when you first wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

The last command is saved in the history. Bash has an `fc` command that gives you access to that information (from `man bash`):

```
fc [-e ename] [-lnr] [first] [last]
fc -s [pat=rep] [cmd]
```

> The first form selects a range of commands from first to last from the history list and displays or edits and re-executes them.  First  and  last may be specified as a string (to locate the last command beginning with that string) or as a number (an index into the history list, where a negative number is used as an offset from the current command number).  If last is not specified it is set to the current command  for  listing  (so  that  ``fc -l -10'' prints the last 10 commands) and to first otherwise.  If first is not specified it is set to the previous command for editing and -16 for listing.
>
> The -n option suppresses the command numbers when listing.  The -r option reverses the order of the commands.  If the -l  option  is  given,  the commands  are  listed  on standard output.  Otherwise, the editor given by ename is invoked on a file containing those commands.  If ename is not given, the value of the FCEDIT variable is used, and the value of EDITOR if FCEDIT is not set.  If neither variable is set,  vi  is  used.   When editing is complete, the edited commands are echoed and executed.
>
> In the second form, command is re-executed after each instance of pat is replaced by rep.  Command is intepreted the same as first above.  A useful alias to use with this is `r="fc -s"'', so that typing`r cc'' runs the last command beginning with `cc'' and typing`r'' re-executes the last command.
>
> If the first form is used, the return value is 0 unless an invalid option is encountered or first or last specify history lines out of range.  If the -e option is supplied, the return value is the value of the last command executed or failure if an error occurs with the  temporary  file  of commands.  If the second form is used, the return status is that of the command re-executed, unless cmd does not specify a valid history line, in which case fc returns failure.

There is also a command named `history`. The manual explains that in details. I'm not too sure which one would better fit your needs.

Further, to get the time, you may want to look into setting up the HISTTIMEFORMAT. However, I'm not too sure how you could access the amount of time spent by the process. Maybe the TIMEFORMAT should be used instead. Otherwise, the Unix way is to run the command with the `time` command. That will generate output of various time and resources used by the process while running.

From the manual (`man time`):

> time run the program COMMAND with any given arguments ARG....  When COMMAND finishes, time displays information about resources used by COMMAND (on the standard error output, by default).  If COMMAND exits with non-zero status, time displays a warning message and the exit status.